# Very elementary question on isosceles triangles, Geometry

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have an isosceles triangle with sides $l,l,k$. Is it a definition that we always must have that $l \geq k $ or this need to be proved ?

MY thought on how to prove this: Call $\alpha$ the angle opposite to $l$ and $\beta$ the angle opposite to $k$. We know $l \geq k $ iff $\alpha \geq \beta $. If $\beta > \alpha $, then $180 = 2\alpha + \beta > 3 \alpha $ and so $60 > \alpha $, but how can we argue that this indeed gives us a contradiction? Perhaps I am going through a bad route on showing this. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It need not be the case that $l \geq k$. However using the triangle inequality (which says sum of two sides is always greater than or equal to the third side) you can have  $l \geq \dfrac{k}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an isosceles right triangle : $k=\sqrt 2\ l$. We have $l\lt k$.

So, we don't always have $l\ge k$.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a definition that we always must have that $l≥k$?

No. I believe that triangles like the 45-45-90 triangles are also isosceles.

In other words, you can have $l\geq k$ and $k\geq l$ and even $k=l$ and those are all isosceles triangles.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a very flat isosceles triangle, e.g., $ l$ can be even 51 percent of $k$. Only imitation being the triangle inequality should be obeyed.